# Comunicate between main GUI interface and top level GUI interface

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, toplevel

I have a problem between communication of GUI's. My program consists on one main interface that is created  on
`class maininterface():`
and other top level interface that it is created in a different class:
`class Interface_PowerBalance()`. The main interface controls the other top level interfaces. My issue is that I wan't to receive info of some attributes of the toplevel interfaces into the main interface and I don't achieve it.

Here there is the `class maininterface():` where I create the main GUI.

```
class mainInterface():

    def __init__(self,root,title):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.Widgets()
    def Widgets(self):
        self.PowerBalanceLabel=Label(self.root,text='Power balance is:')
        self.PowerBalanceLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.Button_InterfacePowerBalance=Button(root,command=self.PowerBalanceframe)
        self.Button_InterfacePowerBalance.grid(column=0,row=0)
        
    def PowerBalanceframe(self):
        self.Power=Interface_PowerBalance(self.root,'Power balance interface').PowerBalance()
        self.PowerBalanceLabel.config(text='Power balance is: '+str(self.Power))
```

When I click `self.Buttton_InterfacePowerBalance` the program creates the top level interface that is in  `class Interface_PowerBalance()` with the next code:

```
class Interface_PowerBalance():
    """ This class creates the interface to obtain the power balance """
    def __init__(self,root,title):
        self.root=root
        self.PowerBalanceFrame=Toplevel(self.root)
        self.PowerBalanceFrame.title(title)
        self.value=DoubleVar()
        self.valueList=[]
        self.Widget()
    def Widget(self):
        self.myentry_value = Entry(self.PowerBalanceFrame,textvariable=self.value)
        self.myentry_value.grid(row=2,column=2)
        self.Button1=Button(self.PowerBalanceFrame, text='Insert a device', command=self.StoreData)
        self.Button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    def StoreData(self):
        self.valueList.append(self.value.get())
        self.PowerBalance()
    def PowerBalance(self,*args):
        self.Power=float(self.Power)
        N=len(self.valueList)
            for j in range (0,N):
                self.Power=self.Power+float(self.valueList[j])
        self.PowerLabel=Label(self.PowerBalanceFrame,text=str(self.Power))
        self.PowerLabel.grid(row=6,column=2)
        return self.Power
```

What my programs do rigth now is receive the `self.Power` attribute from `class Interface_PowerBalance():`when this toplevel interface is opened and show it in the main interface in the `self.PowerBalanceLabel`.
What I want to do is receive `self.Power` attribute from `class Interface_PowerBalance():` **each time this attribute is changed** and show it in the main interface in the `self.PowerBalanceLabel`.

I don't know if it makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a variable power in the `mainInterface`, because you want to keep track of it always:

```
class mainInterface():
    def __init__(self,root,title):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.Widgets()
        self.Power = 0.0 # Here you will store the Power value
```

Second, you will not change the value of the label in the `PowerBalanceFrame` method because you are not binding the `toplevel` to know when it is closing, so change it to:

```
def PowerBalanceframe(self):
    Interface_PowerBalance(self,'Power balance interface').PowerBalance()
```

The trick now is in how you create your `toplevel`. You want it to edit the label of the maininterface so you have to pass the main as parameter (see I passed `self` as parameter instead of `self.root`), so you have to change the `__init__` of the `Interface_PowerBalance`:

```
class Interface_PowerBalance():
    """ This class creates the interface to obtain the power balance """
    def __init__(self,main,title):
        self.main = main # here main is the main interface
        self.root=main.root # thus main.root is the root
        self.PowerBalanceFrame=Toplevel(self.root)
        self.PowerBalanceFrame.title(title)
        self.value=DoubleVar()
        self.valueList=[]
        self.Widget()
```

now you can access `main.Power` and the `main.PowerBalanceLabel`, so just change the `PowerBalance` method to:

```
def PowerBalance(self,*args):
    N=len(self.valueList)
    for j in range (0,N):
        self.main.Power=self.main.Power+float(self.valueList[j])
    self.PowerLabel=Label(self.PowerBalanceFrame,text=str(self.main.Power))
    self.PowerLabel.grid(row=6,column=2)
    self.main.PowerBalanceLabel['text'] = "Power balance is: " + str(self.main.Power) #here is where you edit the main GUI
```

This will work but I shall warn you that your code is not very good. First it would be much better if you used the `mainInterface` as children of the `tk.Tk`. Second that you could use tkinter variables to keep track of the power and use bind to identify when it is changed. And last but not least, variables should be lowercase and classes uppercase.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. When you say that I should use `mainInterface` as children of the `tk.Tk`, what do yo mean?

Comment: take a look in Python Inheritance. If you do `class MainFrame(tk.Tk)` by creating the mainframe you will automatically create the main window, thus you don't need to do `root=tk.Tk()` and pass the root to the mainframe since the mainframe self will be the root